# Symfony2 How to manipulative entity data inside model layer?

Tags: symfony

Symfony2 How to manipulative entity data inside model layer? Can I use Entity Manager outside controller and how? How to get data from Database inside my model class?

Comment: You really shouldn't...

Answer (score 0):

First of all where you want to use your Entity Manager?
If you want to do some operation inside your entity, it's impossible.

You can use entity manager in:
 1. Controller - as you know
 2. Service - you have to set in your service. The best solition for some operation like crypt password for User entity
 3. Command - like in controller

Other way is using own Entity Repository

The question is: what you have to do?

Comment: I want to use it inside my php class, not inside entity, for business logic.

Comment: So the best solution it will be services